# Why my jQuery svg plugin does not work?

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-svg

Suppose we have the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.svg.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="canvas">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And jQuery code:

```
 $().ready(function () {
            var mysvg = $("#canvas").svg("get");
            mysvg.rect(20, 10, 100, 50, 10, 10, { fill: '#666'});         
        });
```

When I run this code the firebug gives me an error:

> TypeError: mysvg.rect is not a function

Please help me out how can i fix this problem

Comment: Are you sure, SVG plugin is getting loaded properly?

Comment: @Akki619: As you see in my html file i have been added this library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach an SVG canvas to the element first:

```
$('#canvas').svg();
```

Then you can retrieve the SVG instance:

```
var mysvg = $('#canvas').svg('get');
```

#### [Check the documentation](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html)